# delete row from database on notification button click

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-notifications

I am kind of newbie to android. I am making an app which will send notification on which two buttons will be provided such as 'helpful' and 'not helpful'.
If the user clicks on 'helpful' user will be redirected to activity.java and if user clicks on 'not helpful' that record will be deleted from sqlite database. Code for that is as following,

**Notification**

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100})
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Content Title")
            .setContentText("Content Text");

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bus);
    builder.setContentTitle("Your bus schedule");
    builder.setContentText("Your bus for "+ search );
    Spinner dropdown2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    Spinner dropdown3 = findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    String join = "-";
    String ConcatedString1 = dropdown2.getSelectedItem().toString().concat(join).concat(dropdown3.getSelectedItem().toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("username",ConcatedString1);
    PendingIntent pIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, " helpful", pIntent1) // #0
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "not helpful ", pIntent)  // #1

            .build();


    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(SecondClass.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

here on first button i have added action from pintent and on other action from pintent1 and on pintent i have getBroadcast which will redirect to notificationaction where that row in database will be deleted.

**Notificationaction**

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");
    if (action.equals("Sunday-09")) {
        performAction1(action);
    } else  {
        performAction2(action);

    }
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    context.sendBroadcast(it);
}

public void performAction1(String action)
{
    DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    myDb.deleteData(action);
}
public void performAction2(String action)
{
    DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    myDb.deleteData(action);
}
```

**Manifest**

```
  <receiver android:name=".NofificationAction"></receiver>
```

**Databasehelper**

```
 public void deleteData(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL( "delete from search_table where name='" + name + "'");

}
```

But when i click on not helpful i can still see the record. Can anyone help me. Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)), `execSQL`:

> Execute[s] a single SQL statement that is NOT a
>   SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

Instead you should use [`delete`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

Comment: I did       db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COL_2 +"="+name,null); still facing same problem

Comment: also tried String whereClause = "name=?";
        String whereArgs[] = {name};
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,whereClause,whereArgs);